# Minimising inconclusive range for binary classification with two thresholds

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, constraints

### Background

I have an optimisation problem related to a binary classification tasks.

I have arrays of probabilistic predictions, $x$, and true binary labels, $y$,  i.e. $x_i\in [0,\,1]$ and $y_i\in \{0,\,1\}$, $\forall i \in [N]$, where $N$ is the length of the vectors $x$ and $y$.

I want to optimize the trade-off between the true positive rate (TPR), true negative rate (TNR), and the number of inconclusive predictions.

More precisely, I want to minimise the number of inconclusive predictions ($|S|$, where $S$ is the set of excluded indexes), constrained on TPR and TNR exceeding some given constants $p$ and $q$, over the threshold variables $a$ and $b$, where $0 < a < b < 1$. Model predictions between $a$ and $b$ are considered inconclusive, and hence excluded.

### Problem Definition

The problem can formally be defined as the following **constrained minimisation** problem:

$$
\begin{align}
\min_{a,\,b} \quad\quad & |\{ i \mid a \leq x_i < b \}| & (|S|)\\
\text{subject to} \quad\quad & \\
& TNR - p > 0, & (TNR > p)\\
& TPR - q > 0, & (TPR > q)\\
& b - a > 0, & (b > a)\\
& a > 0, & (a > 0)\\
& b > 0, & (b > 0)\\
& 1 - a > 0, & (a < 1)\\
& 1 - b > 0, & (b < 1)\\
\text{where} \quad\quad & &\\
& TNR = \frac{TN}{TN + FP}, &\\
& TPR = \frac{TP}{TP + FN}, &\\
& z_i = \mathbb{1}\left[x_i \geq b\right], &\\
& TN = \sum_{i \notin S} \mathbb{1}[y_i = 0, z_i = 0], &\\
& FP = \sum_{i \notin S} \mathbb{1}[y_i = 0, z_i = 1], &\\
& TP = \sum_{i \notin S} \mathbb{1}[y_i = 1, z_i = 1], &\\
& FN = \sum_{i \notin S} \mathbb{1}[y_i = 1, z_i = 0], &\\
& p,\, q \in (0,1). &
\end{align}
$$

#### Bound-Constrained Minimisation

I have also considered if the constrained minimisation problem can be reformulated into a bound-constrained minimisation problem. However, the TPR and TNR constraints are more complex and not simple linear constraints. As far as I know, these constraints cannot be directly translated into bounds for $a$ and $b$.

### Coding Attempt

While my question is mathematical in nature, I describe my attempts to solve the problem programmatically to highlight my issues. I am using *Python* with the *minimize* function from the *optimize* module in the *scipy* package ([scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)).

```
from typing import Tuple
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix


def objective_function(
    thresholds: Tuple[float, float],
    probs: np.ndarray,
    targets: np.ndarray,
) -> float:
    a, b = thresholds
    included_indices = (probs < a) | (probs >= b)
    # exclusion rate
    r = 1 - float(np.mean(included_indices))
    return r


def calculate_rates(
    targets: np.ndarray,
    probs: np.ndarray,
    thresholds: Tuple[float, float],
) -> Tuple[float, float]:
    a, b = thresholds
    idx = (probs < a) | (probs >= b)
    y_true_non_excluded = targets[idx]
    y_pred_non_excluded = (probs[idx] >= b).astype(int)
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(
        y_true_non_excluded,
        y_pred_non_excluded,
    ).ravel()
    tpr = tp / (tp + fn) if (tp + fn) > 0 else 0
    tnr = tn / (tn + fp) if (tn + fp) > 0 else 0
    return tpr, tnr


def constraint_tnr(
    thresholds: Tuple[float, float],
    probs: np.ndarray,
    targets: np.ndarray,
    p: float,
) -> float:
    tnr = calculate_rates(targets, probs, thresholds)[1]
    return tnr - p


def constraint_tpr(
    thresholds: Tuple[float, float],
    probs: np.ndarray,
    targets: np.ndarray,
    q: float,
) -> float:
    tpr = calculate_rates(targets, probs, thresholds)[0]
    return tpr - q


def optimize_thresholds(
    probs: np.ndarray,
    targets: np.ndarray,
    p: float,
    q: float,
    initial_guess: Tuple[float, float],
) -> Tuple[float, float]:

    # Constrained minimization
    constraints = (
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint_tnr, 'args': (probs, targets, p)},  # TNR > p (1)
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint_tpr, 'args': (probs, targets, q)},  # TPR > q (2)
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda thrs: thrs[0]},                         # 0 < a   (3)
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda thrs: 1 - thrs[1]},                     # b < 1   (4)
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda thrs: thrs[1] - thrs[0]},               # a < b   (5)
        # (3) and (5) => b > 0
        # (4} and (5) => a < 1
    )

    # Bounds for a and b (0 < a ≤ b < 1)
    # bounds = [(0, 1), (0, 1)]
    # Method COBYLA cannot handle bounds. Therefore, we use constraints instead.    
 
    # Run the optimization
    result = minimize(
        objective_function,
        x0=initial_guess,
        args=(probs, targets),
        method='COBYLA',
        # bounds=bounds,
        constraints=constraints,
    )

    # Check if the optimization was successful and display the results
    if result.success:
        optimal_a, optimal_b = result.x
        # exclusion rate
        optimal_r = objective_function((optimal_a, optimal_b), probs, targets)

        # Calculate TNR and TPR for the non-excluded cases
        non_excluded_indices = (probs < optimal_a) | (probs >= optimal_b)
        y_true_non_excluded = targets[non_excluded_indices]
        y_pred_non_excluded = (probs[non_excluded_indices] >= optimal_b).astype(int)
        optimal_tnr, optimal_tpr = calculate_rates(
            y_true_non_excluded, y_pred_non_excluded, (optimal_a, optimal_b)
        )

        print(f'Optimal a: {optimal_a}, Optimal b: {optimal_b}')
        print(f'Exclusion rate r: {optimal_r}')
        print(f'True Negative Rate: {optimal_tnr}')
        print(f'True Positive Rate: {optimal_tpr}')
    else:
        print(result)
        raise ValueError('Optimisation was not successful.')

    return optimal_a, optimal_b


def main() -> None:
    df = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv')
    x = df['x'].to_numpy()
    y = df['y'].to_numpy()

    # works
    optimize_thresholds(x, y, p=0.9, q=0.9, initial_guess=(0.2, 0.8))

    # does not work
    optimize_thresholds(x, y, p=0.9, q=0.9, initial_guess=(0.3, 0.7))

    # optimal solution
    optimal_thresholds = (0.3610841998732966, 0.6057616712011725)
    # does not work
    optimize_thresholds(x, y, p=0.9, q=0.9, initial_guess=optimal_thresholds)
```

### Issue

With an initial guess of $a = 0.2$ and $b = 0.8$, i.e.

```
# setup x, y
...
optimize_thresholds(x, y, p=0.9, q=0.9, initial_guess=(0.2, 0.8))
```

it converges to a seemingly optimal solution:

```
Optimal a: 0.370554470806464, Optimal b: 0.5917056391027792
Exclusion rate r: 0.13576158940397354
True Negative Rate: 0.9005128205128206
True Positive Rate: 0.9002911208151383
(0.370554470806464, 0.5917056391027792)
```

However, when $a$ and $b$ are initialised to most other values, even values close to the optimal solution, e.g. $a = 0.37$ and $b = 0.6$, it fails to find a solution.

```
 message: Did not converge to a solution satisfying the constraints. See `maxcv` for magnitude of violation.
 success: False
  status: 4
     fun: 0.13355408388520973
       x: [ 3.719e-01  5.891e-01]
    nfev: 18
   maxcv: 0.000944081336238245

ValueError: Optimisation was not successful.
```

I would like to improve the stability of the my solution, to not depend on a seemingly arbitrary choice of initialisation.

### Alternative methods

With **SLSQP**, the optimisation fails if the initialisation does not satisfy the constraint related to TNR, and TPR, and returns the initialisation values otherwise, i.e. a sub-optimal solution with TNR and TPR unnecessarily high, leading to a larger number of excluded cases than the optimal solution.

I would be happy with any form of input and guidance!

I have previously asked my question in a modified form in Stack Overflow ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77626140/minimizing-inconclusive-range-for-binary-classification-with-two-thresholds)), however, since my question is really mathematical in nature, I am asking it here.

### Sample data

[sample_data.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/bd6j6zcetxt5ymfazskh8/sample_data.csv?rlkey=nwguy7dvxi4e1j6vafl2m0lg3&dl=0)

### Similar problem

I have found a paper that addresses a similar problem; however, instead of constraints on the TPR and the TNR independently, they have a constraint on the overall accuracy.

Patrone PN, Bedekar P, Pisanic N, et al. Optimal decision theory for diagnostic testing: Minimizing indeterminate classes with applications to saliva-based SARS-CoV-2 antibody assays. *Mathematical Biosciences*. 2022 Sep 1;351:108858. doi: [10.1016/j.mbs.2022.108858](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.mbs.2022.108858).

Comment: Can you please share the $x$ and $y$ data for your example?

Comment: @RobPratt I have added a link to sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can linearize the problem and use a mixed integer linear programming solver, which will find a globally optimal solution without relying on an initial solution.

Besides the decision variables $a$, $b$, $z_i$, TN, FP, TP, and FN that you have already introduced, let binary decision variables $\ell_i$ and $s_i$ indicate whether $x_i<a$ or $a \le x_i < b$, respectively.  Introduce a small positive constant tolerance $\epsilon$ to replace strict inequalities with weak inequalities.  The problem is to minimize $$\sum_{i=1}^N s_i$$ subject to
\begin{align}
0 \le a \le b &\le 1 \tag1\label1 \\
\ell_i + s_i + z_i &= 1 && \forall i \tag2\label2 \\
x_i - a + \epsilon &\le (x_i-0+\epsilon)(1-\ell_i) && \forall i \tag3\label3 \\
a - x_i &\le (1-x_i)(1-s_i) && \forall i \tag4\label4 \\
x_i - b + \epsilon &\le (x_i-0+\epsilon)(1-s_i) && \forall i \tag5\label5 \\
b - x_i &\le (1-x_i)(1-z_i) && \forall i \tag6\label6 \\
\text{TN} &= \sum_{i:y_i=0} \ell_i \tag7\label7 \\
\text{FP} &= \sum_{i:y_i=0} z_i \tag8\label8 \\
\text{TP} &= \sum_{i:y_i=1} z_i \tag9\label9 \\
\text{FN} &= \sum_{i:y_i=1} \ell_i \tag{10}\label{10} \\
\text{TN} &\ge p(\text{TN}+\text{FP}) \tag{11}\label{11} \\
\text{TP} &\ge q(\text{TP}+\text{FN}) \tag{12}\label{12}
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} is clear.
Constraints \eqref{2} through \eqref{6} enforce the definitions of the binary variables.  For example, \eqref{3} enforces the logical implication $\ell_i = 1 \implies x_i \le a - \epsilon$.
Constraints \eqref{7} through \eqref{10} define the confusion matrix in terms of the binary variables.
Constraints \eqref{11} and \eqref{12} linearize the ratio constraints for the true negative and true positive rates.

For your sample data, the optimal objective value is $160$, attained for example by $(a,b)=(0.36256, 0.60603)$.

---

By request, here is SAS code:

```
data indata;
   infile 'sample_data.csv' dlm=',' firstobs=2;
   input x y;
run;

proc optmodel;
   set OBS;
   num x {OBS}, num y {OBS};
   read data indata into OBS=[_N_] x y;

   num p = 0.9, q = 0.9, eps = 1e-6;

   var a >= 0 <= 1;
   var b >= 0 <= 1;
   var l {OBS} binary;
   var s {OBS} binary;
   var z {OBS} binary;

   min NumExcluded = sum {i in OBS} s[i];

   con a_le_b:
      a <= b;

   con Partition {i in OBS}:
      l[i] + s[i] + z[i] = 1;
   con Indicator1 {i in OBS}:
      l[i] = 1 implies x[i] <= a - eps;
   con Indicator2 {i in OBS}:
      s[i] = 1 implies x[i] >= a;
   con Indicator3 {i in OBS}:
      s[i] = 1 implies x[i] <= b - eps;
   con Indicator4 {i in OBS}:
      z[i] = 1 implies x[i] >= b;

   var TN, FP, TP, FN;
   con TNcon:
      TN = sum {i in OBS: y[i] < 0.5} l[i];
   con FPcon:
      FP = sum {i in OBS: y[i] < 0.5} z[i];
   con TPcon:
      TP = sum {i in OBS: y[i] > 0.5} z[i];
   con FNcon:
      FN = sum {i in OBS: y[i] > 0.5} l[i];

   con TNRcon:
      TN >= p * (TN + FP);
   con TPRcon:
      TP >= q * (TP + FN);

   solve;

   create data outdata(drop=i) from [i] x y l s z;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you be willing to also provide the code used?

Answer (score 0):

This is just building on top of the answer provided by @RobPratt, for someone reading this thread and who is, like me, more used to Python than SAS.

Here is a Python implementation for the solution by @RobPratt.

```
### Step 1: Imports
import pandas as pd
import pulp

### Step 2: Define Your Data
indata = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv')
x = indata['x'].to_numpy()
y = indata['y'].to_numpy()
N = len(x)

### Step 3: Set Up the PuLP Problem

# Constants
p = 0.9
q = 0.9
eps = 1e-6

# Initialize the optimization problem
problem = pulp.LpProblem('Binary_Classification', pulp.LpMinimize)

### Step 4: Define Decision Variables

# Threshold variables
a = pulp.LpVariable('a', 0, 1)
b = pulp.LpVariable('b', 0, 1)

# Binary decision variables for each observation
l = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('l', range(N), cat='Binary')
s = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('s', range(N), cat='Binary')
z = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('z', range(N), cat='Binary')

# Variables for confusion matrix elements
TN = pulp.LpVariable('TN', lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
FP = pulp.LpVariable('FP', lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
TP = pulp.LpVariable('TP', lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
FN = pulp.LpVariable('FN', lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')

### Step 5: Objective Function

# Objective: Minimize the number of inconclusive predictions
problem += pulp.lpSum([s[i] for i in range(N)])

### Step 6: Constraints

# Constraint 1: a <= b
problem += a <= b

# Constraints 2-6: Definitions of binary variables
for i in range(N):
    problem += l[i] + s[i] + z[i] == 1
    problem += x[i] - a + eps <= (1 - l[i]) * (x[i] - 0 + eps)
    problem += a - x[i] <= (1 - s[i]) * (1 - x[i])
    problem += x[i] - b + eps <= (1 - s[i]) * (x[i] - 0 + eps)
    problem += b - x[i] <= (1 - z[i]) * (1 - x[i])

# Constraints 7-10: Confusion matrix elements
problem += TN == pulp.lpSum([l[i] for i in range(N) if y[i] == 0])
problem += FP == pulp.lpSum([z[i] for i in range(N) if y[i] == 0])
problem += TP == pulp.lpSum([z[i] for i in range(N) if y[i] == 1])
problem += FN == pulp.lpSum([l[i] for i in range(N) if y[i] == 1])

# Constraints 11-12: TNR and TPR constraints
problem += TN >= p * (TN + FP)
problem += TP >= q * (TP + FN)

### Step 7: Solve the Problem
problem.solve()

### Step 8: Print the Results
print('Status:', pulp.LpStatus[problem.status])
print('Optimal value of a:', a.varValue)
print('Optimal value of b:', b.varValue)
```